# How to find the solution to dependent linear equations in constant time?

Tags: arrays, algorithm, math, data-structures

Here is a sample question i have :

Madhav went to Riya's Birthday Party. He was a geek so he had no idea regarding which gift she'l like.
So he took an array of integers with him. The array followed a particular order. First element of array is 1.
Second element of array is 6.
Other elements of the array are two less than the mean of the number preceding and succeeding it.
As it is obvious, Riya felt that this idea was stupid and hence she wanted to punish Madhav.
She decided to ask Madhav the nth number of the array. If he tells the wrong answer, she would slap him.
Help Madhav to escape from this embarrassing situation.

Input : First line contains T , number of test cases and the next T lines contain N , the Nth element of the above array to be found.

Output:

For each test case, output an integer which is the Nth number of the array. As the answer can be very large, output it modulo 109+7

Constraints:

1 ≤ T ≤ 105
1 ≤ N ≤ 1018

SAMPLE INPUT

2

1

3

SAMPLE OUTPUT

1

15

Explanation
First test case is trivial as a [1] = 1. In second test case, a[2]=(a[1]+a[3])/2-2. Substituting the values of a [1] and a[2] , we get: 6=(1+a[2])/2-2. So, a[2]=8*2-1=15

The above question needs to be solved in constant time and space .  How to find the nth number of such linear equations which goes on building solution from first 2 fixed numbers ( 1 , 6  here ) ?

Comment: Suggest an edit to remove the cute story, which only hides the actual specification of the sequence.

Comment: Are those numbers `10^9`, `10^5`, and `10^18`? The exponents have apparently disappeared.

Comment: Actually, looking closer I suggest closing this and asking on https://math.stackexchange.com/ -- however, there you'll also probably need to remove the cute story, to expose the actual maths.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The equation corresponds to

```
a[n] = (a[n-1] + a[n+1])/2 - 2
```

This can be rewritten as

```
a[n+1] = 2(a[n]+2) - a[n-1]
```

Expressing `a[n] = a[n-1] + b[n]` and calculating the first values of `b[n]`:

```
b[1] = 1; b[2] = 5; b[3] = 9; b[4] = 13; b[5] = 17; etc.
```

It is easy to see that `b[n] = 4(n-1) + 1`

It is possible to check this general formula by induction. Then, it follows that

```
a[n] = a[n-1] + 4(n-1) + 1
```

And then

```
a[n] = 4(n-1) + 1  
     + 4(n-2) + 1  
     + 4(n-3) + 1  
     + ...  
     + 1
```

Finally, using that

```
sum_(i=0)^(n-1) (i) = n(n-1)/2
```

We can conclude that

```
a[n] = 2n(n-1) + 4n = n(2n-1)
```

When programming it, pay attention to overflow!

Comment: Please explain how u wrote a[n] = a[n-1] + 4(n-1) + 1 , using a[1] = 1 , a[2] = 6 , also how u reduced the big expression to a[n] = n(2n-1)

Comment: @Nateshbhat I tried to complete a little bit. Hope it is more clear now